# WordPress - How to select specific values from a table column

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to select latitude and longitude values from the WordPress post_meta table.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
meta_id + post_id + meta_key + meta_value // columns
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  12    +   25    + lp_options + a:32:{s:12:"tagline_text";s:36:"Legendary sushi maestro in your town";s:8:"gAddress";s:47:"86 East Pine Street, Seattle, WA, United States";s:8:"latitude";s:10:"47.6152846";s:9:"longitude";s:19:"-122.30498549999999";s:6:"mappin";s:0:"";s:5:"phone";s:14:"(206) 441-8844";s:8:"whatsapp";s:0:"";s:5:"email";s:27:"codewithdeveloper@gmail.com";s:7:"website";s:24:"http://sushikashiba.com/";s:7:"twitter";s:19:"https://example.com";s:8:"facebook";s:19:"https://example.com";s:8:"linkedin";s:19:"https://example.com";s:7:"youtube";s:19:"https://example.com";s:9:"instagram";s:19:"https://example.com";s:5:"video";s:43:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMxLKOv_3t0";s:7:"gallery";s:0:"";s:12:"price_status";s:14:"ultra_high_end";s:10:"list_price";s:0:"";s:13:"list_price_to";s:0:"";s:7:"Plan_id";s:1:"0";s:16:"lp_purchase_days";s:0:"";s:11:"reviews_ids";s:0:"";s:15:"claimed_section";s:11:"not_claimed";s:26:"listings_ads_purchase_date";s:0:"";s:30:"listings_ads_purchase_packages";s:0:"";s:4:"faqs";a:2:{s:3:"faq";a:2:{i:1;s:11:"Specialties";i:2;s:7:"History";}s:6:"faqans";a:2:{i:1;s:153:"Legendary sushi maestro, Chef Shiro Kashiba brings his authentic and innovative Edomae style of sushi and acclaimed Japanese cuisine to downtown Seattle.";i:2;s:226:"Chef Shiro Kashiba started Seattle's first sushi bar in 1970 after years of grueling training alongside world renown sushi chef Jiro Ohno in Tokyo. Chef Shiro Kashiba introduced his masterpiece, Sushi Kashiba in December 2015.";}}s:14:"business_hours";a:6:{s:6:"Monday";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:7:"02:00pm";s:5:"close";s:7:"11:00pm";}s:7:"Tuesday";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:7:"02:00pm";s:5:"close";s:7:"11:00pm";}s:9:"Wednesday";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:7:"02:00pm";s:5:"close";s:7:"11:00pm";}s:8:"Thursday";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:7:"02:00pm";s:5:"close";s:7:"11:00pm";}s:8:"Saturday";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:7:"02:00pm";s:5:"close";s:7:"11:00pm";}s:6:"Sunday";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:7:"02:00pm";s:5:"close";s:7:"11:00pm";}}s:11:"campaign_id";i:93;s:14:"changed_planid";s:0:"";s:19:"listing_reported_by";s:0:"";s:16:"listing_reported";s:0:"";s:13:"business_logo";s:0:"";}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use get_post_meta() and maybe_unserialize()

```
  $lp_options = get_post_meta(25, 'lp_options');
  $lp_options = maybe_unserialize($lp_options);

  $lat = $lp_options['latitude'];
  $lng = $lp_options['longitude'];
```

Test your variables if exist/not empty :)